# How to install/use puppeteer on a machine without root access?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Are there any instructions available about how to setup Puppeteer (https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) on a server where neither root access nor NodeJS is available?
Or is this whole idea nasty and I should rather talk with the administrator about it?

Comment: You can't use nodejs without nodejs.

Comment: I thought/hoped there would exist some kind of bundled version (all-in-one).

Comment: Regarding AIO, you can use Docker to run things on server and not depend on server environment. But of course, you will need root access to install it. Then it can be managed without root or sudo, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install NodeJS locally and add it's *bin* directory to the *PATH* environment variable. Afterwards you can call *npm i puppeteer* as if NodeJS was installed globally.

Comment: Adding the bin directory to PATH didn't work, adding the path to the node.exe file did work. Additionally, installing puppeteer didn't work as, for me, it requires `mkdir 'C:\Windows\node_modules'` and I need admin to add a folder in that folder.